# Crystal Reports formula to grouping field

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, crystal-reports-2008

I am trying to create a formula in Crystal Reports which would return the grouping field depending on what group the formula is placed. For example, if the formula inserted in the group row 'Month', the formula should return ‘command.month’.  If the formula inserted in the group row 'Year', the formula should return ‘command.year’. Can anyone help with this, please?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to dynamically change the grouping? like if your column gives some values; based on that value you will decide whether it should be a month or a year...right?

Comment: Well, not exactly. Values in column are all in texts for all groups.What I want is if I place the formula in Group#1, it will return the field Group#1 is grouping for. If I place the same formula in Group#2, it will return the field Group#2 is grouping for.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your date field format is **MM/DD/YYYY** then you can use below condition in Formula field. and use this formula field in grouping.

if {YourGroupFieldValue }='month' then

left({DateField}',2)

else if {YourGroupFieldValue }='Day' then

mid ({DateField}',2,2)

else

right({DateField}',4)

It should work because i have used it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Actually, my groups are text field, not date or month. I was justing giving 'Month' and 'Year' as an examples. This will not work for the text field.

Answer (score 1):

Consider you have two groups Month and Year. Add one formula in month group. In that formula create a shared variable as shown below.

```
Shared numbervar num:=0;
```

Create another formula in Year group. In that formula create a same shared variable as shown below.

```
Shared numbervar num:= 1;
```

Now create third formula, in that formula add below declaration.

```
Shared numbervar num;
if num = 0 then {your logic}
else if num =1 then {your logic};
```

Put your third formula in both groups and run the report. Same formula will show different values in different groups. I hope I got you this time... :)

Comment: I am trying to something more complex than that. I want to create a formula which would display the grouping field in the Group header depending on which group I place the formula.Let me give another example. Hopefully, I can explain better this time. I have three groups. Group#1=Manager, Group#2=Salesman, Group#3=Product. When I place the formula in Group#1 header, it will display 'Manager'. When I place the same formual in Group#2 header, it will display 'Salesman' and so on...

Comment: Thank you. I will try your suggestion and will post the update.